# vector.exceptions.VectorOperationError: xlLinSetChannelParams failed (XL_ERR_INVALID_PORT) [Error Code 118]

Tags: python, canalyzer

I try to set params for lin channel via XL Driver Library, but i get 118 error (XL_ERR_INVALID_PORT)

```
xlOpenDriver()
xlSetApplConfig('test'.encode(), 0, XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VN1640, 0, 0, XL_BusTypes.XL_BUS_TYPE_LIN)

channel = xlGetChannelIndex(XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VN1640, 0, -1)
mask = xlGetChannelMask(XL_HardwareType.XL_HWTYPE_VN1640, 0, -1)
port = XLportHandle(xldefine.XL_INVALID_PORTHANDLE)
access_mask = xlclass.XLaccess()

baudrate = 19200
params = XLlinStatPar(XL_LINMode.XL_LIN_MASTER, baudrate, XL_LINVersion.XL_LIN_VERSION_2_1, 0)

xlOpenPort(port, 'test'.encode(), mask, access_mask, 256, XL_InterfaceVersion.XL_INTERFACE_VERSION,
           XL_BusTypes.XL_BUS_TYPE_LIN)

print(xlLinSetChannelParams(port, access_mask, params))
```

What do I do wrong?

I checked port is a lin